# Which Star Wars comics does this page (featuring Emperor Palpatine's throne room) come from?

Tags: star-wars, episode-identification

Which *Star Wars* comic does this page (featuring the Emperor Palpatine's throne room) come from?

[image]

Comment: Since the top image is merely a copy of the bottom one (with the dialogue removed), I didn't see the point of posting both.

Answer (score 8):

This image is from [*Shadows of the Empire, #1*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Empire_1)

[image]

Comment: Not to be confused with [this almost identical image](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/dd/Vadersquest_throneroom.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20190414014245) from *Vader's Quest, #2*